# Seemingly inconsistent Makefile behavior (w/ Fortran)

Tags: module, makefile, fortran

I have just started working with Fortran in the past year for work, and it's really my first significant experience with compiled languages.  At work we use a development environment which manages compilation and linking.  In an effort to get my Fortran game up, however, I have started implementing data structures and algorithms at home.  Consequently, I am stepping into Makefiles for the first time.

I have only two programs at this point, implementations of a [Linked List](https://github.com/choct155/algorithms/tree/master/data_struct/LinkedList) and the [Quick Find](https://github.com/choct155/algorithms/tree/master/union_find) algorithm.

The (ridiculously basic) [Makefile I wrote for the Linked List program](https://github.com/choct155/algorithms/blob/master/data_struct/LinkedList/Makefile) links and compiles without a hitch.  I attempted to model the [Quick Find Makefile](https://github.com/choct155/algorithms/blob/master/union_find/Makefile) after the Linked List example, but for some reason it fails to generate the .mod file.  Furthermore, if I explicitly generate the .mod file via the following...

```
gfortran -c QuickFindUF.f90
```

...the Makefile will compile and link the rest without complaint.  I am sure I am making a rookie mistake, but if anyone could identify my oversight, it would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:  In response to the comment, I am adding the contents of the makefiles:

*Linked List*

```
# Makefile for the LinkedList test collection

# Define function to compile and link component scripts
ll_test: LinkedListTest.o LinkedList.o
    gfortran -o ll_test LinkedListTest.o LinkedList.o

# Define functions for each script that compile without linking
LinkedList.mod: LinkedList.o LinkedList.f90
    gfortran -c LinkedList.f90

LinkedList.o: LinkedList.f90
    gfortran -c LinkedList.f90

LinkedListTest.o: LinkedListTest.f90
    gfortran -c LinkedListTest.f90

# Define housekeeping function
clean:
    rm LinkedListTest.o LinkedList.o ll_test
```

*Quick Find*

```
# Makefile for the union_find collection

# Define function to compile and link component scripts
u_find: union_find.o QuickFindUF.o
    gfortran -o u_find union_find.o QuickFindUF.o

# Define functions for each script that compile without linking
QuickFindUF.mod: QuickFindUF.o QuickFindUF.f90
    gfortran -c QuickFindUF.f90

QuickFindUF.o: QuickFindUF.f90
    gfortran -c QuickFindUF.f90

union_find.o: union_find.f90
    gfortran -c union_find.f90

# Define housekeeping function
clean:
    rm union_find.o QuickFindUF.o u_find
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order of the files in:

```
# Define function to compile and link component scripts
u_find: union_find.o QuickFindUF.o
    gfortran -o QuickFindUF.o u_find union_find.o
```

`union_find.f90` depends on the module generated by `QuickFindUF.f90` but it's compiling `union_find` first so the module it needs does not exist yet.

If you switch the order so it builds `QuickFindUF` first it would work:

```
# Define function to compile and link component scripts
    u_find: QuickFindUF.o union_find.o
        gfortran -o QuickFindUF.o u_find union_find.o
```

But a better thing to do would be to make use of that mod dependency that they have listed but doesn't do anything:

```
QuickFindUF.mod: QuickFindUF.o QuickFindUF.f90
    gfortran -c QuickFindUF.f90

QuickFindUF.o: QuickFindUF.f90
    gfortran -c QuickFindUF.f90

union_find.o: union_find.f90 QuickFindUF.mod #Add the module dependency to union_find
    gfortran -c union_find.f90
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Changing the order worked (with slight modification), but I am still not clear on why the Linked List Makefile worked without any problems.  `LinkedListTest.f90` also depends on the module generated by `LinkedList.f90`.  Can this be explained?

Comment: Point taken francescalus, thanks for following up.  The slight modification referenced in the above comment is as follows:   `# Define function to compile and link component scripts
u_find: QuickFindUF.o union_find.o
 gfortran -o u_find QuickFindUF.o union_find.o `

Comment: @MarvinWardJr  You must have already compiled the module before hand. If you were to start clean and delete the .mod and the .o and tried to run the makefile it would fail (It did for me).

Comment: That is an interesting outcome.  I just tested a clean run and it worked just fine for me.  You definitely have `QuickFindUF.o` before `union_find.o`?